# Rationale behind ORM inheritance (JPA)

Tags: inheritance, jpa, architecture, orm

I have come across ORM inheritance in JPA and always wondered about the design principle behind that.

I find it dirty that the framework enables an inheritance relationship between two classes that model a table in a relational database - Liskov substitution principle goes out of the window in most real world cases, except for perhaps examples and tutorials.

In what cases would one *want/need* to use inheritance? Isn't it a bad design by definition? Would joins not serve the purpose in these cases?

I am thinking the people who came up with inheritance for ORM thought about this and there *must* have been an overriding need to enable inheritance in ORM despite it's design flaws (at least in my eyes). What is that need? Why does this flawed design concept of inheritance even exist in ORM?

Reference for ORM inheritance in JPA --> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use inheritance in your classes if your classes require inheritance concepts. You (almost always) don't design a model around what your chosen persistence solution is capable of handling. ORM is (should be) nothing to do with that choice. ORM simply has ways of persisting inheritance trees.

Comment: Yes, I agree about inheritance. But, my thinking is that under NO circumstance is an inheritance relationship between two entities that model a table in a relational database valid. I cannot think of a valid scenario for this.

Comment: perhaps if you actually provide sample classes to highlight what you're trying to say then it may be understandable.